# Comparing effect of two variables

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I have two IV’s (A) and (B) and a DV (X). The hypothesis is: *(A) has a higher propensity to result in (X) than (B).*

X is Dichotomous. 
A and B are single 5-point Likert-scale questions.

I’m struggling to find out which test I should use to test the above. I believe it's a non-parametric test, but I am not certain which one. Can someone kindly advise?

Comment: This is not well formed. Do you mean to ask whether A has a larger effect on X than B does? If so, does it make sense to talk about absolute units of (A) and (B) or standardized units? Does it make sense to treat (A) and (B) as continuous or do the bins represent qualitatively different levels?

Comment: Unless you are performing a controlled experiment in which you can vary the values of $A$ and $B$ (which scarcely seems possible) and subsequently observe $X,$ it's difficult to see how you could conduct any test at all that tells you about "propensity."  Are you really trying to evaluate such an assertion, or is it possible you want to use your data to *find out to how and to what degree $A$ and $B$ might be related to $X$?*